# how to know on which CPU interrupt handler is handled in linux

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, linux-device-driver, interrupt

On multiple processor system, it is quite possible that interrupts can be handled on multiple processors. Is there a way to check where (means on which CPUS) does my interrupt handler is executed on linux kernel ?

Answer (score 4):

`cat /proc/irq/NNN/smp_affinity` tells you on which CPUs the interrupt is allowed to run. It will run on one of the CPUs in the mask.

`cat /proc/interrupts` gives you counters, showing how many interrupts there were on each CPU, for each interrupt number. This tells you where interrupts actually happened.